# MVC Create A Partial View In A Modal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

So I have a partial view called _CreateClient that needs to be passed a ClientEditViewModal that should get passed from the controller like so:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ClientEditViewModel viewModel = new ClientEditViewModel();
        return PartialView("_CreateClient", viewModel);
    }
```

But in my Index view I need to call the partial as a modal window and I am doing it like this:

```
<div class="mfp-hide">   
    @Html.Partial("_CreateClient")
</div>
```

However my Index view needs to take an IEnumerable of ClientModel and I am getting this error when I try to render the Index view:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[Project.Models.ClientModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Project.ViewModels.ClientEditViewModel'.
```

How do I get the view passed to the _CreateClient and keep it in the modal? Or is there a better way to go about doing this?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Index Action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IEnumerable<ClientModel> clients = clientService.GetAll();
    return View(clients);
}
```

Index View:

```
@model IEnumerable<TechUCRM.Models.ClientModel>
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_UserLayout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@section alert {
    @if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.alert))
    {
        <div class="alert alert-@ViewBag.alertType" role="alert">
            @ViewBag.alert
        </div>
    }
}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 text-left">
        <h2>Clients</h2>
    </div>


    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
        <label for="#add-client-btn">New Client</label>
        <a href="@Url.Action("Create")" id="add-client-btn" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></i></a>

    </div>


    <div class="mfp-hide">  
        @Html.Partial("_CreateClient") <!--Need to be passed ClientCreateViewModel-->
    </div>

</div>


<div class="row">
    @foreach(var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12" style="margin-top:20px;">
            <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">@item.Name</a>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

EDIT:

Ok so I figured it out... I feel a little ridiculous because all I needed to do was to give the partial a new ViewModal... yep

ANSWER:

```
@Html.Partial("_CreateClient", new ClientCreateViewModal())
```

Comment: the error is self explanatory you should pass a model with type `Project.Models.ClientModel` to partial view

Comment: Can you show your `Index` action and view?

Comment: You're passing `IEnumerable<ClientModel>` to the partial view, which expects `ClientModel`. Filter the `Model` based on your condition and pass `ClientModel` object. Like `@Html.Partial("_CreateClient", Model.First())`

Comment: @MikeDebela So the partial view needs a ClientCreateViewModel not a ClientModel

Comment: Oh sorry, I don know the relation b/n `ClientModel` and `ClientCreateViewModel`. But if `ClientCreateViewModel` is light weight : `@Html.Partial("_CreateClient", (ClientCreateViewModel)ViewBag.Client)`. Set the `ViewBag` in your `Index` action

Comment: That seems to work! Thanks

Comment: @SamRedmond wouldn't it be better to use `@Html.Action("[action]", "[Controller]") ` instead of `@Html.Partial()`

Comment: @denchu would that still allow me to make that a modal popup with magnific popup or any other modal library?

Comment: Do not add answers in your question. Add your own answer and accept it to close this out.

Answer (score 0):

```
@model ClientEditViewModel
@Html.Partial("_CreateClient", Model);
```

You can pass the model as the second argument.

Comment: The issue is that I can only use 1 model statement and my Index page where the partial is being called already needs a model statement.